# Printdcoument not print as it code

Tags: vb.net

I am working on window project in vb.net. I have used printpreview dialog and print document for printing. I had noticed that some time printdocument not generate as it been code means its ignore what are the changes made its generate old output. So anyone out can resolve my problem.

Here is my code

```
  Dim y% = 10
    Dim headerf = New Font("verdana", 13, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim normalf = New Font("verdana", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Rajesh Dalal", New Font("Verdana", 25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 290, 30)
    'Rectangle
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Drawing.Rectangle(60, 100, 740, 110)) 'rectangle small 
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Drawing.Rectangle(60, 230, 740, 800)) 'rectangle biggest
    'Small rectangle contents
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Shop Name : ", headerf, Brushes.Black, 80, 120)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(StrConv(lblShopName.Text, VbStrConv.ProperCase), New Font("verdana", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 220, 120)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Duration : ", headerf, Brushes.Black, 80, 160)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ddfrom.Value.Date.Day & "/" & ddfrom.Value.Date.Month & "/" & ddfrom.Value.Date.Year, New Font("verdana", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 220, 160)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("To", headerf, Brushes.Black, 345, 160)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ddto.Value.Date.Day & "/" & ddto.Value.Date.Month & "/" & ddto.Value.Date.Year, New Font("verdana", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 400, 160)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Now.Date.Day & "/" & Now.Date.Month & "/" & Now.Date.Year, New Font("verdana", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 620, 120)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Bill Date : ", headerf, Brushes.Black, 600, 120)
```

Comment: Sorry, the question/problem description makes no sense.

Comment: While i am compiling my project its ignor new changes.It not happen before

Comment: Is this code located in form's paint event?

Comment: So this really has nothing to do with printing and is a compilation issue, right? If your project fails to build then there will be no new output to run, so that may be the issue. Sometimes, VS will fail to overwrite the old output for some reason. In that case, you can simply delete the 'bin' and 'obj' folders from your project folder and you should be good to go.  You may need to close VS in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project folder goto debug folder and and find exe file as match to your project name delete that file and compile your project again